# Unable to set a user profile property back to uneditable for Administrators

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I wanted to edit the Account Name (login) for a single user in our on-premises farm, so I went to User Profile Properties in SharePoint central admin, found the Account Name property and in Edit settings I set ["Allow users to edit values for this property"](http://nbsp.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/Images/eusp/2012-01-24-ProfilePicOffice365-05.png)

I was able to make the update fine. I then changed the Account Name edit setting back to "Do not allow users to edit values for this property", but found that I was still able to update the Account Names for users (to begin with I wasn't able to, changing the edit settings was necessary).

With the following script I was able to determine that the IsAdminEditable property of AccountName was still true. IsUserEditable is false.

```
    $site = Get-SPSite http://mycentraladmin:port
    $serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site
    $upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext)
    $accountNameProperty = $upm.Properties | where { $_.Name -eq "AccountName" } 
    $accountNameProperty.IsAdminEditable
    $accountNameProperty.IsUserEditable
```

IsAdminEditable is readonly here. My question is how can I set it back to false and make Account Name uneditable for **both** admins and users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no supported way to change this, so my suggestion would be just to use T-SQL to make the modification.

```
USE [ProfileDB]
UPDATE dbo.ProfileSubtypePropertyAttributes SET IsAdminEditOnly = 0, IsEditable = 0 WHERE PropertyId = 3;
```

Comment: Does editing the ProfileDB put SharePoint in an unsupported state for Microsoft,, as for Content Databases?

Comment: Technically, yes. The other way to go about this is Reflection, also unsupported and more complicated. What I would suggest is opening up a PSS case. They can then "approve" any otherwise unsupported methods, such as direct T-SQL edits/Reflection.